# Create graph from recursive JSON data using apoc.load.json and use UNWIND and FOREACH for setting property

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to create a graph from my recursive JSON file. My JSON data is given below.

```
  "ChildNodes":[
    {
      "ChildNodes":[
        {
          "ChildNodes":[
            {
              "ChildNodes":[
                {
                  "ChildNodes":[
                    {
                      "FSId":1,
                      "FileDetailId":1862,
                      "FileId":1225,
                      "FileName":"tables",
                      "Type":[
                        "DI"
                      ],
                      "collapsed":1
                    }
                  ],
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":1861,
                  "FileId":1224,
                  "FileName":"Components",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                },
                {
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":1885,
                  "FileId":1247,
                  "FileName":"Filters",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                },
                {
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":1894,
                  "FileId":1253,
                  "FileName":"SFXPlugins",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                },
                {
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":1899,
                  "FileId":1255,
                  "FileName":"SonicResources",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                },
                {
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":1901,
                  "FileId":1257,
                  "FileName":"style",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                },
                {
                  "ChildNodes":[
                    {
                      "ChildNodes":[
                        {
                          "ChildNodes":[
                            {
                              "FSId":1,
                              "FileDetailId":1905,
                              "FileId":1262,
                              "FileName":"Symphony",
                              "Type":[
                                "DI"
                              ],
                              "collapsed":1
                            }
                          ],
                          "FSId":1,
                          "FileDetailId":1904,
                          "FileId":1260,
                          "FileName":"Symphony",
                          "Type":[
                            "DI"
                          ],
                          "collapsed":1
                        }
                      ],
                      "FSId":1,
                      "FileDetailId":1903,
                      "FileId":1259,
                      "FileName":"NTSC",
                      "Type":[
                        "DI"
                      ],
                      "collapsed":1
                    },
                    {
                      "ChildNodes":[
                        {
                          "ChildNodes":[
                            {
                              "FSId":1,
                              "FileDetailId":1910,
                              "FileId":1267,
                              "FileName":"Symphony",
                              "Type":[
                                "DI"
                              ],
                              "collapsed":1
                            }
                          ],
                          "FSId":1,
                          "FileDetailId":1909,
                          "FileId":1265,
                          "FileName":"Symphony",
                          "Type":[
                            "DI"
                          ],
                          "collapsed":1
                        }
                      ],
                      "FSId":1,
                      "FileDetailId":1908,
                      "FileId":1264,
                      "FileName":"PAL",
                      "Type":[
                        "DI"
                      ],
                      "collapsed":1
                    }
                  ],
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":1902,
                  "FileId":1258,
                  "FileName":"Styles",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                }
              ],
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":1860,
              "FileId":1216,
              "FileName":"CreateDisc",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            },
            {
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":1913,
              "FileId":1269,
              "FileName":"de-DE",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            },
            {
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":1994,
              "FileId":1298,
              "FileName":"en-US",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            },
            {
              "ChildNodes":[
                {
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":2050,
                  "FileId":1328,
                  "FileName":"X02",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                }
              ],
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":2049,
              "FileId":1327,
              "FileName":"MCX",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            },
            {
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":2066,
              "FileId":1330,
              "FileName":"MediaRenderer",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            },
            {
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":2091,
              "FileId":1335,
              "FileName":"sk-SK",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            },
            {
              "ChildNodes":[
                {
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":2108,
                  "FileId":1359,
                  "FileName":"de-DE",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                },
                {
                  "FSId":1,
                  "FileDetailId":2116,
                  "FileId":1361,
                  "FileName":"en-US",
                  "Type":[
                    "DI"
                  ],
                  "collapsed":1
                }
              ],
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":2106,
              "FileId":1350,
              "FileName":"wow",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            }
          ],
          "FSId":1,
          "FileDetailId":1856,
          "FileId":1103,
          "FileName":"ehome",
          "Type":[
            "DI"
          ],
          "collapsed":1
        },
        {
          "FSId":1,
          "FileDetailId":2120,
          "FileId":1363,
          "FileName":"en",
          "Type":[
            "DI"
          ],
          "collapsed":1
        },
        {
          "FSId":1,
          "FileDetailId":2122,
          "FileId":1365,
          "FileName":"en-US",
          "Type":[
            "DI"
          ],
          "collapsed":1
        },
        {
          "FSId":1,
          "FileDetailId":2135,
          "FileId":1376,
          "FileName":"Fonts",
          "Type":[
            "DI"
          ],
          "collapsed":1
        },
        {
          "ChildNodes":[
            {
              "FSId":1,
              "FileDetailId":3117,
              "FileId":2927,
              "FileName":"config",
              "Type":[
                "DI"
              ],
              "collapsed":1
            }
          ],
          "FSId":1,
          "FileDetailId":2956,
          "FileId":2118,
          "FileName":"System32",
          "Type":[
            "DI"
          ],
          "collapsed":1
        }
      ],
      "FSId":1,
      "FileDetailId":1844,
      "FileId":1051,
      "FileName":"Windows",
      "Type":[
        "DI"
      ],
      "collapsed":1
    },
    {
      "FSId":1,
      "FileDetailId":3813,
      "FileId":3072,
      "FileName":"$OrphanFiles",
      "Type":[
        "DI",
        "IN"
      ],
      "collapsed":1
    }
  ],
  "FSId":1,
  "FileDetailId":0,
  "FileId":5,
  "FileName":"C:",
  "Type":[
    "DI"
  ],
  "collapsed":1
}
```

I found solution in this link useful to me for building my graph - https://community.neo4j.com/t/import-nodes-from-recursively-structured-json/11704
I was able to build the graph with the help of above mentioned link. I used the query given below.

```
WITH 'file:///part-of-VTree.json' AS json_file
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"..FileId") YIELD value AS result 
WITH json_file, result.result AS keys 
UNWIND range(0,size(keys)-1) AS i 
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"..[?(@.FileId == '" + toString(keys[i]) + "')].ChildNodes[*].FileId") YIELD value AS children
WITH keys[i] AS parent_key, children.result AS children
MERGE (parent:GroupNode {name: parent_key})
WITH parent, children
UNWIND children as child_key
MERGE (child:GroupNode {name: child_key})
MERGE (child)-[:CHILD_OF]->(parent)
RETURN *
```

This created a graph with nodes having "FileId" mentioned on it , as I was giving "FileId" as "name" property. When I change my query as below

```
WITH 'file:///part-of-VTree.json' AS json_file
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"..FileId") YIELD value AS result 
WITH json_file, result.result AS keys 
UNWIND range(0,size(keys)-1) AS i 
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"..[?(@.FileId == '" + toString(keys[i]) + "')].ChildNodes[*].FileId") YIELD value AS children
WITH keys[i] AS parent_key, children.result AS children
MERGE (parent:GroupNode {Fid: parent_key})
WITH parent, children
UNWIND children as child_key
MERGE (child:GroupNode {Fid: child_key})
MERGE (child)-[:CHILD_OF]->(parent)
RETURN *
```

It gives me a graph with nodes which has nothing mentioned on it. Earlier I was getting nodes with "FileId" mentioned on it.
what I want is nodes with "FileName" mentioned on it and "FileId" as its property.

With my current query I am not able to set properties for my node. Is there any way to set properties for my node and display "FileName" on nodes. "FileName" is not always unique so I can't create graph by extracting all "FileName" instead of "FileId".
"FileId" is always unique in my case.

Can anyone help me in some way to get my desired result. I need some help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved. This is the query I used :

```
WITH 'file:///part-of-VTree.json' AS json_file 
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"$..FileId") YIELD value AS result 
WITH json_file, result.result AS keys UNWIND range(0,size(keys)-1) AS i 
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"$..[?(@.FileId == '" + toString(keys[i]) + "')].ChildNodes[*].FileId") YIELD value AS children 
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"$..[?(@.FileId == '" + toString(keys[i]) + "')].FileName") YIELD value AS rname
CALL apoc.load.json(json_file,"$..[?(@.FileId == '" + toString(keys[i]) + "')].ChildNodes[*].FileName") YIELD value AS cname
WITH keys[i] AS parent_key, children.result AS children, rname.result AS rn, cname.result AS cn
MATCH (n {name:parent_key})
WITH n, children,rn,cn
UNWIND children AS child_key
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:CHILD]->(m {name:child_key})    
WITH n, rn, cn, collect(m) AS siblings
UNWIND range(0,size(rn)-1) AS k
SET n.label=toString(rn[k])
With cn,siblings
UNWIND range(0,size(cn)-1) AS j
FOREACH(j IN range(0, size(siblings)-1) |
 FOREACH (p1 in [siblings[j]] |
  Set p1.label=toString(cn[j])
 ))
RETURN *
```

Hope this would help someone.